# Django request.is_ajax returns False when using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, django

I'm sending cross-domain ajax request and on another end `request.is_ajax()` gives `False`

```
var text = getSelectedText();
  text = 'text';
  if (text){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            console.log(this.responseText)
        }
    };

    xhttp.open("GET", "http://example.com/text=" + encodeURIComponent(text), true);
    xhttp.send();}
```

Comment: What is your browser?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have do add it manually (as [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and other libraries does):

```
xhttp.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
```

Comment: No, I use jQuery :-) Do you see the header in the network panel?

Comment: Make sure the case of the header value is correct. `is_ajax()` does a [strict string comparison](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/_modules/django/http/request/#HttpRequest.is_ajax).